# Custom logs enrichment

Tags: java, logging

I would like analyze, server logs of one specific application.

Log structure looks like

```
<time> <debug level> [<currentModulePath>](<Thread Num>) <Log message>
```

I would like to provide an easy way to track messages going through the log, e.g. coloring only relevant logs rows for chosen message.

The first thing which crossing my mind is to wrap log elements into html tags.

On the other hand the html tags would hassle viewing the log in command line tool like less/VIM.

Doing two separate versions of logs (one in plain text and one html formatted) isn't option either. Logs are too big to keep them in two copies.

I would like to have elements/tags or any other additional info saved in its own file. 
I would build application which would merge original-log file and html-tag file into one html-log file.

I suppose html-tag file could be small. And logs could still be viewed from command line.

Do you think this approach will work ?

Is there any framework/library which can help me ?

Any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaSE has [XMLFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/XMLFormatter.html) out of the box. Although I'm not sure whether it's a good idea, but one can transform an xml file to anything using an appropriate xslt. You could also write your own formatter which would produce a properly structured output.